# jquery javascript loop and sequential function show

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, sequential

I'm working on a jQuery system for an accordion-like slide show, the problem is when i try to create the auto slide for this , i have:

```
for (i=1;i<=5;i++)  { setInterval(acordeon(i),2000) }
```

With this i call inside the loop the function acordeon(i) to be executed each 2000 ms, the problem is it doesn't execute all

The function parameter is the id of the div to show, for example if I have 5 divs to animate I just need to call this function with the right id and it animates just fine, the problem comes when I try to animate this: I need to execute first `acordeon(1)` then `acordeon(2)` ..... 3 , 4 and finally `acordeon(5)`

I tried different methods but it only works when I generate random integers and call `setInterval`

Ok thank´s for all i hope - sure - :) you can help me , Regards

Comment: Can you set up a sample at jsfiddle.net for us to play with, please?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be you are setting those intervals "all together" in like some milliseconds, thus all 5 intervals end at the "same time". Try with:

```
var divToAnimate = 1;

setInterval(function(){ 

    acordeon(divToAnimate);

    divToAnimate = (divToAnimate%5)+1;

},2000);
```

This way you'll call accordeon each 2 seconds with a different i to animate to and then increment it but keeping it in the range 1-5

[here's a jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yz4R8/)

Comment: i use this var i = 0

for (i=1;i<=5;i++)  
{ 

setInterval(function(){ 

    acordeon(i)

    i = ((i+1)%5)+1 

},2000)

} , but only animate the second id , thank´s

Comment: no you don't have to put the for (i=1;i<=5;i++), just use the code I wrote (with var i = 1). if you do the for it iterates form 1 to 5 very fast and sets all the intervals starting almost at the same time thus they'll end together and won't look as you wish, what you need to do is to use the interval of 2000 to call acordeon(i) on a different div each interval. Also consider using semicolons at the end of your command lines

Comment: I added a working jfiddle and edited the increment to i = (i%5)+1; which works as expected

Comment: yes works but only open the first slide , the other no open , and if i have 5 slides ths function call by id the div which must move , for example acordeon (2) and before acordeon(3) , etc , regards and thank´s for your help in this :)

Comment: did you check the jFiddle? what code are you writing? the code works fine, please check my changes and post your code.

Comment: [code]<script>

var w="900";
var w_col="50";
var n_cols="5";
var margin=3*n_cols;

var result=w_col*n_cols+margin;

var final=w-result;


$(function(){



for (i=0;i<=5;i++)
{


$(".ac_"+i+"").css("width",""+w_col);

}

});






function acordeon(id)
{


$(function(){


$(".ac_"+id+"_inf").css("width",""+final);
$(".ac_"+id+"_inf").show(2000).fadeIn(2000);


for (i=0;i<5;i++)
{

if (+id==i)
{}
else
{
$(".ac_"+i+"_inf").hide(1000);
}




}


});


}

 
</script>[/code] it´s my code

Comment: now, you see you used another i in that for cycle, that overrides my i, just use another name for it or write for(var i = 0...) to make it local... http://jsfiddle.net/yz4R8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function:

```
$(div).each(function(){ setInterval(acordeon($(this)),2000)});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a callback to setInterval, instead you are passing the return value of the accordion function. Try this in your for loop:

```
setInterval( function(){ acordeon(i) }, 2000 )
```

Comment: Thnk´s but no works only animate one time and before no works more , 
for (i=1;i<=5;i++)  
{ 

setInterval( function(){ acordeon(i) }, 2000 )

}

Answer (score 0):

This worked quite well for me:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    $('#bullet-' + i).delay(i * 1000 - 1000).fadeIn('fast', function () {
        var id = this
        setTimeout (function () {$(id).css('color', 'lightgray');}, 1500);
    });
}
```